# how to extract word from row

Tags: r, string

I have a 46 MB csv file containing data. Essentially, I would like select only those rows that have particular word like "PRODUCT". There are 600 000 rows for this data. I have used `grep()` to search for the string matching. Following are few lines of my data.

```
head(test)
                                                            Item.Description UQC Year
1                   PHARMACEUTICALS PRODUCTS.(MEDICINE) DOLEYKA SYRUP 100 ML NOS 2015
2                           Multani mati hesh100gm x 160 (AyurvedicProducts) PAC 2015
3             Amla /Shikakai/ Aritha powder 100gm x 160 (Ayurvedic Products) PAC 2015
4                            Godrej h.dye blk 40ml x 36 (Ayurvedic Products) PAC 2015
5 DR. COOLERS HERBAL LOZENGES.(2) DR. COOLERS HERBAL LOZENGES (MINT FLAVOUR) PAC 2015
6                          Eno lemon/ regular 100gm x 48 (AyurvedicProducts) PAC 2015
  Identifier RITC.Code
30049099
30049011
30049011
30049011
30049011
30049011
```

I have used `test[grep("PRODUCT", rownames(test)), ]`. It gives me an error.

Comment: Do you have the "PRODUCT" in the `rownames`  Looks like it is in the `Item.Description` column. i.e. try `test[grep("PRODUCT", test$Item.Description),]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)try grepl, it works better.
2)The upper/lower case matters here, and you have both of them in your text.

So try:

1) test$Item.Description <- tolower(test$Item.Description)
2) products <- test[grepl("product", test$Item.Description),].

And yes, the usage of the needed column (ItemDescription) instead of rownames matters too

Comment: but I want all coloumns?

Answer (score 0):

1. open csv file using ms-excel
2. go to menu 'data' and click 'filter'
3. in filter drop down select 'Text Filters' then select 'contains'
4. then type word 'product'
5. list contains word 'product' will be filtered

Comment: I think OP would prefer an R solution.